# Xcode : how i can know my path is good for my frameworks?

Tags: swift, react-native, frameworks

I tried to plug a frameworks (it's like a scanner for augmented reality) i'm facing about 2 big issues :

- My project is created with react native and i have to plug this framework with swift.

So first of all i created a bridging Header , i import my stuff for react native and also for my framework.

For my framework , i import him on roots projects and on my linking librairie VDARSDK :

[image]

[image]

Then i checked if my path is good on my framework search path

[image]

Despite of that, i have two errors :

[image]

I'd usually code only with react native so i'm not very confortable with swift . Someone can help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

ou can try this solution. I have solved the same problem by this way.

**Product** > **Scheme** > *Edit Scheme* > Select "***Build***" on Left Menu > Find implicit dependencies.

check [Find implict dependencies].
[image]: